# How to partition a dataset to reduce time complexity of kNN?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, knn

I'm using kNN for content based image retrieval.

Datasets often contain more than 10 million images, each image is transformed into a vector with more than 300 dimensions.

This is a lot of data, it's slow to load into memory and find kNN.

I'm wondering if I can somehow partition the dataset into smaller ones, and distribute the smaller datasets among multiple servers.
When querying, I only need to find out the correct partition to look into and only do kNN on that partition.

Comment: How are you doing it now? How is the dataset compressed? How would you prefer to do the parallelisation? Would be useful with some more information... Have you looked into batch processing? If you're using python, sklearn has support for easy-to-setup kNN and batch processing.

Comment: The dataset is not compressed, it's a huge matrix of float32 numbers.

Comment: My current solution is to split the dataset and do kNN on all of the parts concurrently on multiple machines, which is still an O(N) solution. The worst part is that if one of the machines is slow, the whole query suffer.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, I don't think you can get plain kNN to work faster then O(n) (which is what you seem to be after, based on the comments).

However You may want to look into [approximate nearest neighbor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search#Approximate_nearest_neighbor) algorithms. They allow faster search and/ or vastly improved memory footprint, for the price of some preprocessing and non-guaranteed global-optimum (though usually the performance is bound).

Some relevant resources (without knowing what language you're using):

- Spotify's [ANNOY](https://github.com/spotify/annoy) repository has a C++ implementation (with bindings to many languages) plus some additional comparisons and resources, like a thorough [performance comparison](https://github.com/erikbern/ann-benchmarks) between several libraries
- [This repository](https://github.com/ZJULearning/efanna) implements the interesting EFANNA algorithm from a [recent paper](http://Computer%20Science%20%3E%20Computer%20Vision%20and%20Pattern%20Recognition%20EFANNA).